# intel_agp kernel module not found

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I trying to use intel embedded HD 4400 graphics.
As best as I know, it's need to load i915 kernel module (and the kernel module loader also try to load it) without success because it's depends from intel_agp module.

```
root@Laptop:/# lsmod | grep -i intel_
root@Laptop:/# modprobe intel_agp
root@Laptop:/# lsmod | grep -i intel_
```

When i try to load module, there is no error message, but the module is not loaded.

Than I  searched for kernel module file:

```
find /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64 | grep -i intel_agp
(no result)
```

But it's doesn't exists. How can I get this module?

In most of driver topic, there is an output of lsmod which indicate this module loaded.

Comment: It could be compiled in statically, try `grep _AGP /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64`

Comment: Really, it's static. (And I can also found in modules.builtin).
But when i try `modprobe i915` it's fail with "ERROR: could not insert 'i915': No such device"
and dmesg says: "[drm:i915_init] *ERROR* drm/i915 can't work without intel_agp module!"
What can I do now?

Comment: Does `find /sys -name '*agp*'` find anything? What's liste din `/sys/bus/pci/drivers`?